# using es6 functions for matrix calculation

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to make some calculations on elements of a sample matrix, which they are on selective diagonals (here is make a sum on 2 separated diagonals). So i can do it with a for loop easily:

```
let matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]] ;

let sum1=0;
let sum2 = 0;

for (var i=0;i<matrix.length-1;i++) {
  sum1+=matrix[i][i+1];
  sum2+=matrix[i+1][i];
}
console.log(sum1,sum2) ;
```

The question is:
Is possible to do this with es6 functions like reduce, map, etc without for loop?

Comment: Of course it's possible, `reduce` is pretty omnipotent. But it comes down to a loop internally anyway, so don't expect it to be more efficient. Have you tried to use any of them? You can find lots of examples for `sum` functions with `reduce` on the web.

Comment: Btw, these are all from ES5 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with the `reduce()` method:

```js
const matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]];

const sum1 = matrix.reduce((acc, x, i) =>
    acc + (i < matrix.length - 1
      ? x[i + 1]
      : 0
    )
  , 0);

const sum2 = matrix.reduce((acc, x, i) =>
    acc + (i != 0
      ? x[i - 1]
      : 0
    )
  , 0);

console.log(sum1,sum2);
```

Note that both `reduce()` and `map()` were introduced in ES5, not ES6.

Comment: @ARYAMAN Yes. Just use the simple and fast loop that you started with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`

```
var output = matrix.reduce( (a,c,i,ar) => (
    a[0] += ar[i][i+1] || 0 ,  //sum1
    a[1] += (ar[i+1] ? ar[i+1][i] : 0),  //sum2
    a ), //return the accumulator 
    [0,0]); //initial value
```

Output is an array of `[sum1, sum2]`

**Demo**

```js
var matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16]
];
var output = matrix.reduce((a, c, i, ar) => (
    a[0] += ar[i][i + 1] || 0, //sum1
    a[1] += (ar[i + 1] ? ar[i + 1][i] : 0), //sum2
    a), //return the accumulator 
  [0, 0]); //initial value

console.log(output);
```